# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 because of @{}

Tags: ios, xcode

I got a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` `code=1` because of a line like this:

```
NSDictionary* params = @{};
```

I didnt create the project, but i notice that have link to a `c++` library, and have build setting that is not default (the setting generated by `XCode`). If i change this line by

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary new];
```

The issue is gone. Can it be something to do with the compiler's setting in `project's build setting`?

Comment: This line is perfectly fine in intself. It creates an empty, immutable dictionary using a short hand syntax. Without more context (does it happen on app start, on user interaction?) and more code there is no way to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: i update the question, it doesnt not happen when app start, the call is confirm is in main thread. I updated the question for a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment said this error is likely to be deep in your code. If the culprit is a zombie, the easiest way to find it is to run it (preferably in the latest Xcode, currently Xcode 8, as it has been improved) in profiler and choose "Zombies". When it fails, you can see the history of everything that has happened to the object.

Also, set an exception breakpoint. You may get a break when the error happens instead of in main, where the exception gets passed up.

Comment: I do hope there is a typo in your answer. The latest Xcode is number 8, released this month.

Comment: latest xcode should be xcode 7 ( xcode 8 is coming). I updated the question with more context.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/download/ - Xcode 8 released 13th of September.